# USB serial emulation: CDC or vendor-specific?

Tags: microcontroller, serial, usb-device

When designing a device that requires communication with a PC via a virtual serial port over USB:

- When would one use usb-serial port emulation chips with vendor-specific drivers (e.g. FTDI) and
- when would one implement a Communication Device Class (CDC) device?

What are the advantages of each solution, what the limitations?

Comment: By CDC, I assume you meant "Communication Devices Class" and not "Centers for Disease Control". :-P

Comment: @Insilico - Oh damn, in my answer I presumed it was "Canadian Dairy Commission".

Answer (score 5):

It will very much depend on the features your device offers.

The UART-over-USB is an attractive solution because you can use it on any microcontroller which can work with UART, even if it doesn't have the hardware and has to bit-bang it. The FTDI UART-to-USB bridges (there are others as well, like Silicon Labs, but FTDI is the most commonly used) hide all the USB details, so there are no requirement for the microcontroller  concerning this. A microcontroller with 512 bytes of Flash and 2 I/Os can communicate with a PC this way.

CDC is different. It's a USB class, which means you need a USB stack, and the CDC driver. Especially the CDC driver may be a problem on low-end microcontrollers, while they may be available for an RTOS, but then you will probably be running on a more advanced platform. Since you will be running USB software you'll have to get a Vendor ID (VID) and Product ID (PID) if you want to identify it on a USB bus. A license costs money: 2000 dollar for the VID, without which you're not allowed to use the USB logo.

Using FTDI chips solves this problem: FTDI has a VID and PIDs, so that you don't have to worry about it. By default the PID won't be unique to your product (all FT232Rs will have the PID 0x6001, for instance), but the PID is stored in on-chip EEPROM and can be modified. FTDI can provide you with a block of unique PIDs.
For your everyday project I would work with the FTDI chips, since they need no footprint on the microcontroller, and are proven technology.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I'm quite sure that VID/PID on FTDI chips can be changed (I had at least two device with FTDI USB-serial adapter embedded and custom VID/PID. (they need a custom driver too)

Comment: @Axeman - updated my answer. Grazie del feedback!

Comment: IMO the biggest problem FTDI solves for you is providing high-quality, royalty-free host-side drivers. Unless you want to sell your product in hughe numbers (or only for a very limited set of hosts) it will cost you $$$ to come even close. The Windows built-in CDC class driver is of far lower quality. (= almost unuseable fro a serious product).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Your point about the Windows driver is interesting. I would have expected them to be particularly hassle free. Can you elaborate just a bit on what the problems are? Stability? Throughput?

Comment: @stevenvh Thanks for pointing out the VID / PID issue. I had completely forgotten about the licensing issue.

Comment: @ARF my problems were stability, which makes performance aspects uninteresting. Reactions on various fora suggested that others has similar problems.

Comment: @Wouter [service message] Ik denk dat je minstens 4 letters van Arik's naam moet overnemen. Als je "AR" intikt krijg je de hint te zien, maar bij de "F" verdwijnt die. Ik denk niet dat hij hiervan bericht wordt.

Comment: Let's not forget the [MCP2200](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/devices.aspx?dDocName=en546923)!

Answer (score 3):

Generally it is cheaper to select a microcontroller with a built-in USB device interface and run the necessary software to do a CDC virtual com port, than to have an external USB-serial converter.

However, putting a separate converter IC on the board does have some role:

- in updating legacy designs to USB without changing anything else
- keeping the micro controller software very simple - this can also be an advantage for bootloaders, and anything that needs to run counted-cycles realtime, where servicing a USB interrupt could be a problem, yet polling/accepting a single serial character at a time might not be (or you can even do a serial scheme with application-level tolerance for missed characters, since the converter IC continues to respond as a proper USB device)
- or even keeping the interface as a separate tool that is not included in the bulk version of the product
- in adding a USB device-side interface to a PC-derived embedded device which would normally only come with USB host interfaces
- as an end run around the VID/PID concern

Comment: The point about decoupling the USB communication complexity from the rest of the design is a good argument. Also I had not thought about the possibility of only having one USB port which already functions in host mode... Thanks.